# need help hash table in SAS?

Tags: sas

I want to know how many I/O operations (one or many?) it would take for SAS to load a dataset from hard disk to hash table?
My understanding is:
there are three components when people load data from hard disk to hash table, their relationships are below:

Data on hard disk---> memory buffering---->PDV------>hash table(in memory)

the I/O operation is measured when data load from hard disk to memory buffering.
If space of memory buffering is small (smaller than data on hard disk) then it would take memory buffering more than 1 time (or many times) to load data from hard disk to memory buffer before transfer to PDV.

But if memory buffering is big (bigger than data on hard disk), then it can load all the data from hard disk in one go.

I want to know if my understanding is correct?